# Negative lookahead not working with SourceFile

Tags: regex, bash, macos, perl, exiftool

I am trying to edit some files using regular expressions.

`sed` seemed too limited so I switched to Perl.

There might be something wrong in my syntax.

The regex pattern works in TextMate.

Nothing happens when I use Perl.

I want to remove all lines not containing `SourceFile` or `""`.

For your information, it's for cleaning up output data from `exiftools`.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(?!.*(SourceFile|"").*).*$\n//g' out.csv

$ cat out.csv
SourceFile,GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude
1.jpg,,
2.jpg,,
3.jpg,"10 deg 20' 30.30"" N","40 deg 50' 60.60"" W"
4.jpg,"10 deg 20' 30.30"" N","40 deg 50' 60.60"" W"
```

The clean up should keep the first line and all lines containing GPS data. So after clean up it should look like:

```
SourceFile,GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude
3.jpg,"10 deg 20' 30.30"" N","40 deg 50' 60.60"" W"
4.jpg,"10 deg 20' 30.30"" N","40 deg 50' 60.60"" W"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this regex? Include your input & output samples.

Comment: One option, if you can rerun your exiftool command again, would be to tell exiftool to only process files that contained gps coordinates e.g. `exiftool -if '$GPSLatitude and $GPSLongitude' -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude -csv >out.csv TargetDir`

Comment: Thanks @StarGeek ! Most useful help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a line, you don't need to make a replacement. Check the condition and display the line or not:

[edit] It seems you want the opposite that your initial pattern suggests:

perl:

```
perl -ne '/SourceFile|""/&&print' file
```

awk:

```
awk '/SourceFile|""/' file
```

grep:

```
grep 'SourceFile\|""' file
```

---

[old answer]

```
perl -ne '!/SourceFile|""/&&print' file
```

Shorter with awk:

```
awk '!/SourceFile|""/' file
```

or grep:

```
grep -v 'SourceFile\|""' file
```

Comment: @Kasam: I don't see a reason it doesn't work, you probably missed something.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am trying to add more patterns. Replace " deg " with "°" and "'" with "′". And also truncate some of the filenames. Ahh, it would be easy if a regex method worked.

Comment: @Kasam: Since it's a csv file, you can also check if the second field is empty or not.

Comment: Good tip. I didn't know that.